# 2^4 finite field multiplication in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, optimization

I am currently trying to optimize a 4-bit finite field multiplication modulo `X^4 + X^3 + 1` that I've made in VHDL. I did a 16x16 array containing all the results of the multiplications, and when I want to multiply to numbers, for example 8 and 15, i just write `byte_out <= mult_array(8,15)`.

Would you have any advice on how to optimize the calculation ?

PS : here is the entity I made :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity GF_Mult is
port (gf_in_1  : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      gf_in_2  : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      gf_out   : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end GF_Mult;

architecture arch of GF_Mult is

type gfarray is array(0 to 15, 0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

constant GF_MULT_ARRAY : gfarray := 
((x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0", x"0"),
(x"0", x"1", x"2", x"3", x"4", x"5", x"6", x"7", x"8", x"9", x"a", x"b", x"c", x"d", x"e", x"f"),
(x"0", x"2", x"4", x"6", x"8", x"a", x"c", x"e", x"9", x"b", x"d", x"f", x"1", x"3", x"5", x"7"),
(x"0", x"3", x"6", x"5", x"c", x"f", x"a", x"9", x"1", x"2", x"7", x"4", x"d", x"e", x"b", x"8"),
(x"0", x"4", x"8", x"c", x"9", x"d", x"1", x"5", x"b", x"f", x"3", x"7", x"2", x"6", x"a", x"e"),
(x"0", x"5", x"a", x"f", x"d", x"8", x"7", x"2", x"3", x"6", x"9", x"c", x"e", x"b", x"4", x"1"),
(x"0", x"6", x"c", x"a", x"1", x"7", x"d", x"b", x"2", x"4", x"e", x"8", x"3", x"5", x"f", x"9"),
(x"0", x"7", x"e", x"9", x"5", x"2", x"b", x"c", x"a", x"d", x"4", x"3", x"f", x"8", x"1", x"6"),
(x"0", x"8", x"9", x"1", x"b", x"3", x"2", x"a", x"f", x"7", x"6", x"e", x"4", x"c", x"d", x"5"),
(x"0", x"9", x"b", x"2", x"f", x"6", x"4", x"d", x"7", x"e", x"c", x"5", x"8", x"1", x"3", x"a"),
(x"0", x"a", x"d", x"7", x"3", x"9", x"e", x"4", x"6", x"c", x"b", x"1", x"5", x"f", x"8", x"2"),
(x"0", x"b", x"f", x"4", x"7", x"c", x"8", x"3", x"e", x"5", x"1", x"a", x"9", x"2", x"6", x"d"),
(x"0", x"c", x"1", x"d", x"2", x"e", x"3", x"f", x"4", x"8", x"5", x"9", x"6", x"a", x"7", x"b"),
(x"0", x"d", x"3", x"e", x"6", x"b", x"5", x"8", x"c", x"1", x"f", x"2", x"a", x"7", x"9", x"4"),
(x"0", x"e", x"5", x"b", x"a", x"4", x"f", x"1", x"d", x"3", x"8", x"6", x"7", x"9", x"2", x"c"),
(x"0", x"f", x"7", x"8", x"e", x"1", x"9", x"6", x"5", x"a", x"2", x"d", x"b", x"4", x"c", x"3"));

begin

process(gf_in_1, gf_in_2)
begin
    gf_out <= GF_MULT_ARRAY(to_integer(unsigned(gf_in_1)), to_integer(unsigned(gf_in_2)));
end process;


end arch;
```

Answer (score 1):

"optimise" ? no : improve, yes`.

I would do two things :

1. If you can cleanly express the formula in a VHDL function, I would initialise the `gfarray` from that function. It'll be easier to maintain and less error-prone than manually transcribing every value. As it's a constant, the function won't be executed at runtime.
2. Minor : I'd declare the input ports as `natural range 0 to 15` and clean up a lot of unnecessary type conversions - if permitted.

Comment: 1. Actually i don't know the formula, and I wanted to know if someone knew it !
2. If i declare my input as a natural I will have to do a conversion before, so I do not think it could improve the overall design.